# How to convert multiple tables from Excel into JSON

Tags: python, json, excel

I have 2 tables in Excel.

The first one contains the information of companies:

| title | Member_No | Auth_Capital | Email |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| KUWAIT ENERGY CO. KSCC | 100018 | 127000000 | 127000000 |
| SALEM INTERNATIONAL ADVERTISING CO. | 100021 | 10000 |  |
| POWER TOUCH GEN. TRAD. & CONT. CO. | 100026 | 500000 |  |

And the second table contains the information of users and the associated company:

| name | role | nationality | Member_No |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| منصور احمد محمد بوخمسين | Chairman of the board of Directors | KUWAIT | 100018 |
| محمد عادل التميمي | Vice Chairman and Cheif Executive | CANADA | 100018 |
| SALEM M. AL-AJMI | Authorized partner with Doc. | KUWAIT | 100021 |
| ريم محمد سالم الحريص | Partner | KUWAIT | 100026 |
| محمد | Special Power of Attorney | KUWAIT | 100026 |
| سالم | Special Power of Attorney | KUWAIT | 100026 |

However, I want to convert it to JSON.

This is the result of JSON file that I want:

```json
[{"information": {"title": " KUWAIT ENERGY CO. KSCC", "Member_No": " 100018", "Auth_Capital":" 127000000",  "Email": " mansour.aboukhamseen@koc.com.kw"}, "users": [{"name": "منصور احمد محمد بوخمسين", "role": "  Chairman of the board of Directors", "nationality": " KUWAIT"},{"name": "محمد عادل التميمي", "role": "  Vice Chairman and Cheif Executive", "nationality": " CANADA"}]},
{"information":{"title": " SALEM INTERNATIONAL ADVERTISING CO.", "Member_No": " 100021",   "Auth_Capital": " 10000",     "Email": null},  "users": [{"name": "SALEM M. AL-AJMI", "role": "  Authorized partner with Doc.", "nationality": " KUWAIT"}]},
{"information":{"title": " POWER TOUCH GEN. TRAD. & CONT. CO.", "Member_No": " 100026",   "Auth_Capital": " 500000",     "Email": null},  "users": [{"name": "ريم محمد سالم الحريص", "role": "  Partner", "nationality": " KUWAIT"},{"name": "محمد 0 0", "role": "  Special Power of Attorney", "nationality": " KUWAIT"}, {"name": "سالم 0 0", "role": "  Special Power of Attorney", "nationality": " KUWAIT"}]}]
```

I coded the following code which can convert one Excel table to JSON file.

```py
import excel2json

excel2json.convert_from_file('Conpanies.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pandas.
First import your excel files. You can easily convert them to dictionaries with `to_dict` and the parameter `orient="records"`.
Finally build your list of dict to make a json out of it:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

df_c = pd.read_excel("companies.xlsx")
df_u = pd.read_excel("users.xlsx")

data = []
comp_list = df_c.to_dict(orient="records")

for comp in comp_list:
    users = df_u[df_u["Member_No"]==comp["Member_No"]].to_dict(orient="records")
    data.append({"information": comp, "users":users})

print(json.dumps(data, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False))
```

`ensure_ascii=False` makes the arabic characters readable in the json (beware of encoding while opening the json):

```
[
    {
        "information": {
            "title": "KUWAIT ENERGY CO. KSCC",
            "Member_No": 100018,
            "Auth_Capital": 127000000,
            "Email": "foo@bar.com"
        },
        "users": [
            {
                "name": "منصور احمد محمد بوخمسين",
                "role": "Chairman of the board of Directors",
                "nationality": "KUWAIT",
                "Member_No": 100018
            },
            {
                "name": "محمد عادل التميمي",
                "role": "Vice Chairman and Cheif Executive",
                "nationality": "CANADA",
                "Member_No": 100018
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "information": {
            "title": "SALEM INTERNATIONAL ADVERTISING CO.",
            "Member_No": 100021,
            "Auth_Capital": 10000,
            "Email": NaN
        },
        "users": [
            {
                "name": "SALEM M. AL-AJMI",
                "role": "Authorized partner with Doc.",
                "nationality": "KUWAIT",
                "Member_No": 100021
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "information": {
            "title": "POWER TOUCH GEN. TRAD. & CONT. CO.",
            "Member_No": 100026,
            "Auth_Capital": 500000,
            "Email": NaN
        },
        "users": [
            {
                "name": "ريم محمد سالم الحريص",
                "role": "Partner",
                "nationality": "KUWAIT",
                "Member_No": 100026
            },
            {
                "name": "محمد",
                "role": "Special Power of Attorney",
                "nationality": "KUWAIT",
                "Member_No": 100026
            },
            {
                "name": "سالم",
                "role": "Special Power of Attorney",
                "nationality": "KUWAIT",
                "Member_No": 100026
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Thank you so much and if i want to save it  in a json file.

Comment: Simply use `with open("myfile.json", "w") as out_file: json.dump(data, out_file, indent = 4, ensure_ascii=False)`